# Word for small bird-like jumps?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> With tiny [...], the bird scanned its vicinity, completely ignoring
>   me.

I thought of the word *hoppings* but sounds strange and it only has [1](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22with%20little%20hoppings%22&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=TsKsVLeSK4qA8QW0tYLYBQ) Google result.

Is there a better option?

Comment: tiny hops or tiny skips, the bird is hopping/skipping/jumping etc.

Comment: *hop v.* **1.1** (Of a bird or other animal) move by jumping with two or all feet at once: *a blackbird was hopping around in the sun* **1A** hopping movement: *place the rabbit on the floor to have a hop around* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hop

Comment: Yeah, my first thought is "hop".

Comment: You could maybe do something with "jitter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hops*. There is a noun sense of *hop* that means such a tiny jump.

That said, I like "with tiny hoppings" better. It's a reasonable use of the gerund and the sound matches the imagery well but without being so overly poetic as to distract. *Hops* would be more usual, but *hoppings* is more vivid in this particular case.

Comment: Hoppings? I think *hops* is much better, especially because its small size better suits the adjective *tiny*.

Comment: @Robusto but the pitter-patter of the iambic phrase "tiny hoppings", no? Aw well, I did start my answer with *hops* as it would be the more usual.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something a little different, try the noun form of *flit*.

> **flit** *n* A fluttering or darting movement.
>   [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flit)

This adds the sense of using the wings a little, but is not overused like some of the others. You can even blend it with another idiom to make something small and fidgety:

> The tiny bird moved in flits and starts.